# Select rows which contain the same json value

Tags: jquery, json, database, sqlite

Hey guys  small help here::::::

I have a db whose values are as follows:img Can I call the json value of listing_id(23,27....so on) in properties column(with having row value as "listing") using a single query, I would Really Appreciate the help .enter image description here

I'm using sqlite .json extension is not available.what I'm trying to do is::select all the rows having listing_id as a single value(23,27...).Is there any other way?[image]

Comment: What is you mysql version? if it is greater than 5.7, you can use json_extract.

Comment: @RohitMittal OP said he's using sqlite, and apparently a version compiled without support for its json functions (which do include `json_extract()`)

Comment: Yes...is there any way if I change my whole database from sqlite to prosgres or mysql